# Resource namespace not exist if resource file named using culture prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, resources

I have a resource file named `Res.en.resx` in my Asp.Net Mvc 4 project.

In a view I'm trying to access its properties like this: `@MvcApp.Resources.Res.Title` but I'm getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Resources' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

If I change resource name to `Res.resx` everything works fine.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to have at least a file named xxx.resx which contain the translation for the default language of your application.

So if your main language is french and you would like to have an english version, you need:

- xxx.resx file which contain the default language of your app.
- xxx.en.resx file which contain the english version of your file.

Hope this help!